# Magento 2 how to listen to event fotorama fullscreenenter

Tags: magento2.2.2, gallery, fotorama, fotorama-slider

I am not able to listen to event  fotorama:fullscreenenter what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
        $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            console.log('this works!')
            $(this).on('fotorama:ready', function(){
                console.log('this also works!');
            });
            $(this).on('fotorama:fullscreenenter', function(){
                console.log('THIS DOESN\'T WORK!')
            });
        });
        $('[data-gallery-role="gallery"]').on('fotorama:fullscreenenter', function() {
            console.log('THIS ALSO DOESN\'T WORK!'); //Taken from ../magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js lines #184, #191
        });
        $(this).on('gallery:fullscreenenter', function () {
           console.log('ALSO DOESN\T WORK!');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got it!

inside the `gallery:loaded` i can now listen to event fullscreenenter when fullscreen mode shows when image is clicked essentially like so:

```
...
var item = $(document).find('.fotorama-item');
console.log(item);
item.on('fotorama:fullscreenenter',function () {
     console.log('okokokokkokko');
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution! That works! I suggest using "this" instead of "document" to select the fotorama-item. Could get you into trouble if there are multiple galleries on the page.

```
...
var item = $(this).find('.fotorama-item');
item.on('fotorama:fullscreenenter',function () {
    console.log('OK');
}); 
...
```